# Angular-Kendo ComboBox placeholder text not working

Tags: angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have a simple angular-kendo ComboBox on a page without an initially selected value.  It should show the [`placeholder`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#configuration-placeholder) text in that case, but instead it's showing `? undefined:undefined ?`

**HTML**

```
<select kendo-combo-box ng-model="Project" k-options='projectOptions'></select>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {    
  $scope.projectData = [
    {name: 'Bob', value: 1},
    {name: 'Tom', value: 2}
  ];

  $scope.projectOptions = {
    placeholder: "'Select...'",
    dataTextField: 'name',
    dataValueField: 'value',
    dataSource: {
      data: $scope.projectData
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sutK7yOGRjNDmZAA0ckr?p=preview) that shows the problem.  Can anyone spot the cause?

This used to work in an older version of angular-kendo, but it's not working in the current version.

Comment: can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650556/how-to-use-async-await-in-python-child-process

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is somewhat related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1019

The solution is simple: use an `<input>` instead of a `<select>` element:

```
<input kendo-combo-box ng-model="Project" k-options='projectOptions'/>

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.projectData = [
    {name: 'Bob', value: 1},
    {name: 'Tom', value: 2}
  ];

  $scope.projectOptions = {
    placeholder: "'Select...'",
    dataTextField: 'name',
    dataValueField: 'value',
    dataSource: {
      data: $scope.projectData
    }
  }
});
```

([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eA94mVLjlYyHrBZ9Zaaw?p=preview))

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650556/how-to-use-async-await-in-python-child-process

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<Select>` instead of `<input>` you can use simple `placeholder="'Project'"`

For example:

```
<select kendo-combo-box="projectComboBox"
        k-data-source="projectDataSourceBox"
        k-data-text-field="'projectName'"
        k-data-value-field="'projectId'"
        k-ng-model="Dialog.ProjectId"
        k-value-primitive="true"                                        
        k-suggest="true"
        required="required"
        k-auto-bind="false"
        k-filter="'contains'"
        k-change="projectChangeBox"
        style="width: 100%"
        placeholder="'Project'">
        </select>
```