# Angular Kendo Drop down

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I am using angular-kendo ui for a number of components but have encountered an issue which I can't seem to resolve. I have the following angular select which works fine and binds the selected value to the ng-model correctly.

```
 <select ng-model="link.CompanyId" ng-options="obj.Id as obj.Name  for obj in link.PossibleCompanies"></select>
```

Then I add the kendo-drop-down-list argument to convert it to a Kendo DD and it stops binding the selected value of ng-model.

```
 <select kendo-drop-down-list ng-model="link.CompanyId" ng-options="obj.Id as obj.Name  for obj in link.PossibleCompanies"></select>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction of a solution for me able to use the kendo ddl with angular and still have the selected value of ng-model bind to the list.

Comment: This is just a thought but if, by adding the kendo-drop-down-list, you are you adding a new Directive then that will change the element's scope so maybe you need to reference the data in the Directive's scope...? Try running it in Chrome, put a breakpoint in and then check the scope.

Comment: Try using an `input` element instead of a `select` like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023113/angular-kendo-combobox-placeholder-text-not-working

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try using `k-ng-model` and `k-ng-options` rather than `ng-options` and `ng-model`.

Comment: Little correction is required! it is `k-options` instead of `k-ng-options`.