# Angular + Kendo: Default placeholder for drop down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I was wondering how to set placeholder for drop down list in kendo ui + angular.

Currently I have:

**Template**

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list ng-model="selectedElement" k-options="options" >
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
...
$scope.options = {
        dataTextField: 'label',
        dataValueField: 'id',
        dataSource: {
            data: [
                {
                    "label": "Please Select..."
                },
                {
                    "id": "linear",
                    "label": "Sample Linear"
                },
                {
                    "id": "bar",
                    "label": "Sample Bar"
                }
            ]
        }
    };
...
```

If I replace the datasource by a backend call, I cannot have 'Please Select' there. Is there another way of solving this problem?

I tried using **data-option-label="Please Select"** following instructions in this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/placeholder-text), but no luck.

Comment: not sure if it's the same issue but you could try with an input instead of the select: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23029167/2001735

Comment: I tried also that, but did not solve.

Comment: that one is using  kendo-combo-box, which is a different directive, but thanks anyways...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can either define it as a **data** attribute ([more information here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/AngularJS/introduction#widget-options-in-html))

**Template**

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-option-label="'item1'" ng-model="selectedElement" k-options="options" >
</select>
```

or set the [optionLabel](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-optionLabel) option in the $scope

**Controller**

```
...
$scope.options = {
    optionLabel: "Item...",
    dataTextField: 'label',
    dataValueField: 'id',
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {
                "label": "Please Select..."
            },
            {
                "id": "linear",
                "label": "Sample Linear"
            },
            {
                "id": "bar",
                "label": "Sample Bar"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

...

Comment: `k-option-label="item1"` is wrong since option-label is a string so you need to add ' around it like `k-option-label="'item1'"`

Comment: @GeorgeK: hey do you know how to dynamic change the optionLabel? I tried $scope.options.optionLabel = 'new display...'. The UI doesnt get updated

Comment: You will need to use k-rebind*. Here is a demo that demonstrates this http://dojo.telerik.com/ipuzo
* - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-update-upon-option-changes